# Drawing Captured Screen Image in JPanel ,Image is displayed one more time ?How can I fix it to be display one timw?

Tags: java, swing, drawing, java-2d

I Want to capture Image from screen and draw it in JPanel , it works but it is displayed one more time like entering in a loop , I am confused by this , How can I fix it ,Please?
Varibles Iwidth,Ihieght ares above initiaized, but I take the block of code that cause the problem

```
 protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Image img;            
         ImageIcon i = null;            
        Rectangle screenRect=new     Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
         try {
             BufferedImage capture=new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);
             capture.getHeight();
             capture.getWidth();
             i=new ImageIcon(capture);
         } catch (AWTException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(TestDrawing.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
         img = i.getImage();
         g.drawImage(img,Iwidth,Ihieght,null);
         super.repaint();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Never have code like that inside of paintComponent. That method should be reserved for painting and painting only, and is a method that you don't really have full control over since it is called by the JVM in response to both your request, and to requests from the OS, and even if you request a repaint, there's no guarantee that it will be complied with, especially if the requests are stacking up. Also, your GUI's perceived responsiveness will often depend on how quick painting is done, which is while file reading and image capturing should never be done inside of paintComponent.

Instead, you should read the image in as a reaction to some event, perhaps a Timer, then after the image is read, call `repaint()` and in paintComponent draw the obtained image.

Never call `repaint()` inside of paintComponent either.

Something like in pseudo code

```
// inside of the ActionListener of a Swing Timer (if you want to do this repeatedly)
get screen image from robot and feed it into the capture BufferedImage field
consider doing this in a SwingWorker
call repaint() when SwingWorker is done (via a PropertyChangeListener)
```

Inside of paintComponent:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   super.paintComponent(g);
   if (capture != null) {
      g.drawImage(capture, capture.getWidth(), capture.getHeight());
   }
}
```

---

**Edit**

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker.StateValue;

public class ScreenCaptureTest extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 600;
   private static final int PREF_H = 400;
   private JButton btn = new JButton(new ScreenCaptureAction(this,
         "Capture Screen", KeyEvent.VK_C));
   private ImagePanel imagePanel = new ImagePanel();

   public ScreenCaptureTest() {
      JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
      buttonPanel.add(btn);

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(new JScrollPane(imagePanel), BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   }

   public void setImagePanelImage(BufferedImage img) {
      imagePanel.setImage(img);
      revalidate();
      repaint();
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      ScreenCaptureTest mainPanel = new ScreenCaptureTest();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("ScreenCaptureTest");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
   private BufferedImage image;

   public void setImage(BufferedImage image) {
      this.image = image;
      revalidate();
      repaint();
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      if (image != null) {
         g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (image != null) {
         return new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
      }
      return super.getPreferredSize();
   }

}

class ScreenCaptureAction extends AbstractAction {
   private ScreenCaptureTest screenCaptureTest;

   public ScreenCaptureAction(ScreenCaptureTest screenCaptureTest, String name,
         int mnemonic) {
      super(name);
      putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      this.screenCaptureTest = screenCaptureTest;
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      setEnabled(false);
      final SwingWorker<BufferedImage, Void> mySwingWorker = new SwingWorker<BufferedImage, Void>() {

         @Override
         protected BufferedImage doInBackground() throws Exception {
            Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            Dimension screenSize = toolkit.getScreenSize();
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            BufferedImage capture = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(
                  screenSize));
            return capture;
         }

      };
      mySwingWorker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pcEvt) {
            if ("state".equals(pcEvt.getPropertyName())
                  && pcEvt.getNewValue() == StateValue.DONE) {
               setEnabled(true);
               try {
                  screenCaptureTest.setImagePanelImage(mySwingWorker.get());
               } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }
            }
         }
      });
      mySwingWorker.execute();
   }
}
```

---

**Edit**
Note, that if this were my program, I'd display the image as an ImageIcon in a JLabel as it is much simpler to code. Then you could do away with the ImagePanel class and its paintComponent method, and simply code the main as:

```
public class ScreenCaptureTest extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 600;
   private static final int PREF_H = 400;
   private JButton btn = new JButton(new ScreenCaptureAction(this,
         "Capture Screen", KeyEvent.VK_C));
   //!! private ImagePanel imagePanel = new ImagePanel();
   private JLabel screenLabel = new JLabel(); //!!

   public ScreenCaptureTest() {
      JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
      buttonPanel.add(btn);

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      //!! add(new JScrollPane(imagePanel), BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(new JScrollPane(screenLabel), BorderLayout.CENTER); //!! 
      add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   }

   public void setImagePanelImage(BufferedImage img) {
      //!! imagePanel.setImage(img);
      Icon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
      screenLabel.setIcon(icon);
//!!      revalidate();
//!!      repaint();
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      ScreenCaptureTest mainPanel = new ScreenCaptureTest();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("ScreenCaptureTest");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```